# Default size of manually created push buttons

Tags: css, qt

I have created an array of buttons, 6×7. I had not specified any size for these while creating them. So they must have been created in some default size and has correctly aligned into a screen of 320x640.

Now that i have the array of equal sized buttons, I need to find out the pushbuttonsize so as to put the images on them. how to i do that? I could not find any function such as, get size or get height or get width.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qwidget.html) has many methods for this purpose. See width(), geometry(), height(), and size() methods.

Comment: Thank you, 
I got that but, i really dont know how to use them.

In the docs, I found, 

int QSize::height () const
Returns the height.

How do i call the function height()?? using obj of QSize??

This is my code. I jus need to find the height and width of any button


cellBut[i][j]=new QPushButton();
connect(cellBut[i][j],SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(onClickAction()));
Thank you

Comment: QPushButton derives from QWidget, i.e. you can use all QWidget functions directly on it: `cellBut[i][j]->height()`